# ModuleNotFoundError - Airflow error while import Python file

Tags: python, airflow

I created a very simple DAG to execute a Python file using PythonOperator. I'm using docker image to run Airflow but it doesn't recognize a module where I have my .py file

The structure is like this:

```sh
main_dag.py
plugins/__init__.py
plugins/njtransit_scrapper.py
plugins/sql_queries.py
plugins/config/config.cfg
```

cmd to run docker airflow image:

```sh
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v /My/Path/To/Dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags  puckel/docker-airflow webserver
```

I already tried `airflow initdb` and restarting the web server but it keeps showing the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plugins'`

For the import statement I'm using:

```py
from plugins import njtransit_scrapper
```

This is my PythonOperator:

```py
tweets_load = PythonOperator(
    task_id='Tweets_load',
    python_callable=njtransit_scrapper.main,
    dag=dag
)
```

My njtransit_scrapper.py file is just a file that collects all tweets for a tweeter account and saves the result in a Postgres database.

If I remove the PythonOperator code and imports the code works fine. I already test almost everything but I'm not quite sure if this is a bug or something else.

It's possible that when I created a volume for the docker image, it's just importing the main dag and stopping there causing to not import the entire package?

Comment: You use `import plugins.njtransit_scrapper` to import a module from a package.

Comment: Thanks @Goyo I tried both but sadly it's the same result.

Comment: Then the package is not accessible from the place where you are importing it.

Answer (score 3):

To help others who might land on this page and get this error because of the same mistake I did, I will record it here.

I had an unnecessary `__init__.py` file in `dags/` folder.
Removing it solved the problem, and allowed all the dags to find their dependency modules.